# Python Random Project

Tags: python

This is a random code which is similar to my own project code.
When i run it it says UnboundLocalError: local variable 'score' referenced before assignment.  Can anyone fix it.

```
score = 0

def Random_Thing():
    Random_Text = input("Random Text")
    if Random_Text == "Hello":
        score = score + 1
        print(score)

def Random_Thing_2():
    Random_Text_2 = input("Random Text 2")
    if Random_Text_2 == "Hello2":
        score = score + 1
        print(score)

Random_Thing()
Random_Thing_2()
print(score)
```

Comment: It seems to work well for me. Are you sure this code has the problem you are describing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using global variables in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function)

Comment: What error code are you seeing? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

When you define `score = 0` at the top, it is in the global scope for the file. By default, functions have only read access to global variables. You cannot change them. Therefore `print(score)` would work inside a function. But `score=score+1` would not.

If you want to change global variable(s) from inside a function, do `global var1, var2...` at the begining of the function. For your code, you need to do

```
def Random_Thing():
    global score
    #your code

def Random_Thing_2():
    global score
    #your code
```